# jQuery autocomplete on click gets the whole list to the input

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery to do an autocomplete and when I click 1 item on the list the input gets all the items of the list(even the < li >..< /li >)

This is the script which I call

```
       if($_GET['q']) {
        $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['q']);

        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {

            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM .... WHERE name LIKE '%$queryString%'");
            if($query) {
                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {

                    echo "<li>$result->name</li>";


                }
            } else {
                echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
            }
        } else {
            // Dont do anything.
        } // There is a queryString.
    } else {
        echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
    }
```

And this is the jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#ac3").autocomplete({
    url:'searchcond.php',   
     select: function(event, ui) {
        console.dir(ui);
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#ac3").text(ui.item.label);
    }
    });
    });
</script>
```

Also when I type something it does not get it. I have to type it fast to get the correct query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember that jquery autocomplete wants just a list of key|values (one per line) response and not an UL-LI list:

EG:

echo "$key|$value\n";

```
while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
     echo "$result->name\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanxxxxxxxx <3   Believe it or not I thought about adding \n but then I said "it won't make a difference". Stupid me.Need more coffee :P

Answer (score 0):

To fix the correct query, you can add an option to delay or the minChars before the search: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions

To get the text, try: `$("#ac3").text(ui.item.label.text());`

Comment: Thank you but this worked well. I don't know what but it affected the results too!(I mean the above solution)